# Bootstrap 3 Collapse - changing the glyphicon in the panel heading depending on collapse state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that this has been asked several times but I cannot get any of the answers to work in my code.

I am using Bootstrap 3 panels and collapse to show adverts. In the basic view, only the advert heading is shown together with a chevron down glyph to indicate that there is more information.

When the user clicks on the chevron-down, the main panel body containing the advert text is shown. At this point, I would like the chevron-down glyph to change to a chevron-up glyp.

I am using the following code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#Advert').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('#Glyp-Advert').removeclass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down').addclass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
  $('#Advert').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#Glyp-Advert').removeclass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').addclass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a id="Heading-Advert" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Advert">
        Heading
        <span class="pull-right"><span id="Glyp-Advert" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="Advert" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Advert text<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This succeeds in displaying the main advert panel but will not change the glyph.

Any help would be appreciated. Note that the page will contain several adverts; so I intend to repeat the above code several times on the page but change the id's to contain the word 'Advert1' or 'Advert2' etc instead of just 'Advert'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Jonathan Wilson was spot on BUT it failed to mention that the script needs to be AFTER the html and not before in my sample code.

Therefore, the correct code should be

```
<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a id="Heading-Advert" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Advert">
        <span class="pull-right"><span id="Glyp-Advert" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
        Heading
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="Advert" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Advert text<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#Advert').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('#Glyp-Advert').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up');
  });
  $('#Advert').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#Glyp-Advert').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

As such, your calls to `removeclass` and `addclass` are invalid because `removeClass` and `addClass` are the actual method names (notice the capital 'C' in each name).

Your code works otherwise.  See http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/SXYZ2/

Comment: I can see it works in the jsfiddle. But I cannot get the glyph to change on my page after changing the method names to addClass and removeClass. Could there be something else wrong or missing?

Comment: It could be anything. (I can't see your page)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need Javascript.  You can do this with a few CSS styles.  Here's how I've done it.

1. Make sure all your panel-title a links have this class:  accordion-toggle
2. Add this CSS to your style sheet:

.

```
/* symbol for open panels */
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f068";
    float: right;
    color: #474747;
}

/* symbol for closed panels */
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: "\f067";
}
```

Note, I've used FontAwesome here, but you can change the font and characters to whatever you need, such as up and down chevrons.